# Which adjectives can be used in connection with "Chuzpe"?

Tags: usage

This question is constructed to have an excuse to ask a question about the word "Chuzpe"

I want to link to [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuzpe). Please note the section Beispiele. I just find it delicious.

There is an entry in [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chutzpah) too, but without the example.

On twitter I found it used as

> Sag mal, du hast ja schon eine krasse Chuzpe, dich auch noch locker
>   mit mir zu unterhalten.

But I think generally it isn't used together with adjectives. Is that correct?

Comment: Why? "Mit großer Chuzpe ..." - Why not?

Answer (score 1):

It is more often made into an adjective, as in *chutzpahdig*. I like the ah ending because it is more reflective of the Yiddish spelling.

Comment: Huh, I'd never heard that before. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

"Chuzpe" is mostly used alone and not with a qualifying adjective. I suppose if someone is said to have "Chuzpe", then this statement, absolute as it is, is best used on its own - it certainly doesn't need any more *amplification*, and it's quite hard to think of a way to *relativize* it.

See also its [synonyms](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chuzpe)

> "Dreistigkeit, Frechheit, Unverschämtheit, [...] Unverfrorenheit, Schlitzohrigkeit",

which are also only rarely used with an adjective.

Comment: I realize that the link I posted contains "vollkommene Unverfrorenheit", but at least to my ears, this sounds quite strange. That's why I replaced the adjective with an ellipsis.